# In Elixir with Postgres, how can I have the database return the enum values which are NOT in use?

Tags: postgresql, enums, elixir, ecto, processing-efficiency

I have an EctoEnum.Postgres:

```
# @see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217
defmodule PricingEngine.Pricing.CurrencyEnum do
  @options [
    :AED,
    :AFN,
    # snip...
    :ZWL
  ]
  use EctoEnum.Postgres,
    type: :currency,
    enums: @options

  def values, do: @options
end
```

This enum has been included in our Postgres database

We also have a structure:

```
defmodule PricingEngine.Pricing.Currency do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "currencies" do
    field(:currency, PricingEngine.Pricing.CurrencyEnum)

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(currency, attrs) do
    currency
    |> cast(attrs, [:currency])
    |> validate_required([:currency])
    |> unique_constraint(:currency)
  end
end
```

We can currently successfully use the following functions to figure out which currencies are active/used:

```
  def active_currency_isos do
    Repo.all(select(Currency, [record], record.currency))
  end

  defdelegate all_currency_isos,
    to: CurrencyEnum,
    as: :values

  def inactive_currency_iso do
    Pricing.all_currency_isos() -- Pricing.active_currency_isos()
  end
```

This works, but I'm led to believe this could be more efficient if we just asked the database for this information.

Any idea(s) how to do this?

Comment: Should not `active_currency_isos` use `distinct: true` option in call to `select`? Also, I am not sure I understand how one might query the database for the information that is _absent in there_.

Comment: I don't know anything about distinct: true, so I can't comment on any need to use it.  The database contains a complete set of enums.  It also contains a table which may or may  not consume those values.  The idea is to get the values which are used in the table and then return only those enums which were not included in the values collected in the table.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a list of all the used enums you should just do a `distinct` on the currency field. This uses the Postgres `DISTINCT ON` operator:

```
from(c in Currency,
 distinct: c.currency,
 select: c.currency
)
```

This will query the table, unique by the currency column, and return only the currency column values. You should get an array of all of the enums that exist in the table.

There are some efficiency concerns with doing it this way which could be mitigated by materialized views, lookup tables, in-memory cache etc. However, if your data set isn't extremely large, you should be able to use this for a while.

## Edit:

Per the response, I will show how to get the unused enums.

There are 2 ways to do this.

### Pure SQL

This query will get all of the used ones and do a difference from the entire set of available enums. The operator we use to do this is `EXCEPT` and you can get a list of all available enums with `enum_range`. I will use `unnest` to turn the array of enumerated types into individual rows:

```sql
SELECT unnest(enum_range(NULL::currency)) AS unused_enums
EXCEPT (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.name) c.name
    FROM currencies c
)
```

You can execute this raw SQL in Ecto by doing this:

```
Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!(MyApp.Repo, "SELECT unnest(...", [])
```

From this you'll get a `Postgresx.Result` that you'll have to get the values out of:

```
result
|> Map.get(:rows, [])
|> List.flatten()
|> Enum.map(&String.to_existing_atom/1)
```

I'm not really sure of a way to code this query up in pure Ecto, but let me know if you figure it out.

### In Code

You can do the first query that I posted before with `distinct` then do a difference in the code.

```
query = from(c in Currency,
  distinct: c.currency,
  select: c.currency
)

CurrencyEnum.__enums__() -- Repo.all(query)
```

Either way is probably negligible in terms of performance so it's up to you.

Comment: Cheers for the response!  I'm sorry but I was accidentally a little ambiguous in my question.  I actually want the database to return the enums which were _not_ in use (i.e., the inactive values)